# How to Trap Your Moderator

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, sudoku

*You have locked your least favorite moderator behind a 27x27 Sudoku...*
*Now you regret, but you have forgotten how to solve the puzzle...*

[image]

CSV version:

```
 ,  , 1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 7,  ,  ,  ,  , 6, 1,  
6,  ,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  ,  , 2,  , 8, 9,  ,  ,  ,  , 2,  , 4,  , 9,  ,  , 7,  , 9
2,  , 9,  , 7, 6, 3,  ,  , 4,  ,  ,  , 3,  , 4,  ,  ,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  , 4,  , 8
 ,  , 8,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  , 6,  ,  ,  , 6,  ,  ,  , 7,  , 4, 5
 ,  , 4,  , 7,  ,  , 6, 1,  ,  , 5,  , 6,  , 8, 9,  , 2,  ,  , 8,  ,  ,  ,  , 2
 ,  ,  ,  , 1, 2, 4, 3,  ,  , 6, 1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 1,  , 4, 6,  ,  
 , 8,  ,  , 2,  , 5,  , 8,  , 5, 3,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 1, 4,  , 7,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  ,  ,  , 6,  , 3,  ,  
 , 5,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 8,  , 1,  , 5, 3,  ,  ,  , 7,  ,  ,  , 2
 , 7, 5, 8, 3, 9,  , 4,  ,  ,  , 9,  , 4,  ,  , 7,  , 1,  ,  ,  ,  , 6,  , 8,  
 ,  ,  ,  , 6, 4,  ,  , 6,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 8,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  , 5,  ,  ,  ,  , 2
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 5,  ,  , 2, 6,  , 8,  ,  , 7,  ,  , 3,  , 4,  
 ,  ,  , 1,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  , 8,  , 1,  ,  ,  , 9, 5, 8,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  ,  
3,  , 5,  , 8,  ,  , 1, 2, 2,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 1,  , 3,  ,  , 9,  , 6,  ,  , 8,  
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  , 3, 2
9, 1, 6,  , 6,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 7,  , 8, 9,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 9,  , 3,  ,  ,  , 9
4,  ,  ,  , 9,  ,  , 7,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 6,  , 5, 2,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  
 ,  ,  ,  , 2,  ,  , 9,  , 4,  ,  ,  , 1,  ,  ,  ,  , 7,  ,  , 9,  ,  ,  , 1,  
 ,  ,  , 6,  , 9, 6,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 7,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 3, 1,  ,  , 7, 5,  ,  
 ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 9, 4, 4, 1,  ,  ,  ,  , 9,  ,  ,  , 2,  ,  , 6,  ,  ,  ,  
 ,  , 3,  ,  , 1,  , 5, 8,  ,  , 3,  ,  , 8,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  
 ,  , 2,  ,  , 7,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 4,  ,  , 2, 4,  , 4,  ,  , 9, 4,  
 , 8,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 2,  ,  ,  , 3,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 3, 7,  ,  ,  , 3,  ,  ,  
 ,  , 6,  ,  ,  ,  , 8, 7, 5,  ,  , 8,  , 7,  , 1,  ,  ,  ,  , 6,  , 8,  ,  , 7
 , 1,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 2,  ,  ,  , 2,  , 3,  , 5, 2,  , 8, 6,  , 3, 2,  ,  ,  ,  
 , 7, 5,  ,  ,  ,  , 6, 1, 5, 7,  ,  , 8,  ,  ,  ,  , 1,  ,  , 5,  ,  ,  ,  ,  
 ,  , 6,  , 7,  , 3,  , 8,  , 4, 9,  ,  , 6,  ,  ,  ,  , 9, 4,  , 4,  ,  ,  ,
```

Comment: *Avi mumbles angrily while trying to find missing numbers...*

Comment: instructions? are we supposed to know how this is different from a regular sudoku?

Comment: I would have thought you’d have 3 copies of each number in every row / column, but there are four 2s in the last column and other places, so, what’s going on here?

Comment: @Avi I don't understand what does trapping behind a Sudoku means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I notice that there are somewhat thicker lines between each of the traditional-Sudoku squares.  My bet is that that's part of it?  like, each of the standard 9x9 squares is standard sudoku, and then something between the squares as well?  Perhaps another sudoku line running through each unique position on all 9?  (as there are 9 of the traditional squares, set out 3x3, and Sudoku likes 9s)

Comment: Each of the 9x9 squares can't be a standard sudoku tho, cuz look at the top right one,  there are two 2s in the right-most column

Comment: @ShubhamGoenka Nope, that's part of the puzzle :)

Comment: @BenBarden The CSV version doesn't have any distinction between any of the 'lines' though - I'd assume it's just a result of how OP stitched the image together.

Comment: A thought - given that the 27x27 is actually a 9x9 of 3x3 squares, maybe we're supposed to treat each 3x3 square as a single number in a 9x9 sudoku grid - perhaps the number in the center of each 3x3 square is that square's value for the second layer?

Comment: Maybe completely off-base, but - using 'least favourite moderator' as a clue, the mod for Puzzling with the lowest reputation score (from https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) has a Rubik's Cube on the shirt of his avatar. Maybe there's something rotation-related involved here?

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I put the grid into a Google sheet (which can then be downloaded as an excel file): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TPCiGaSZlpqsjQh666qRoGB7B1Xp8zdnjRDJ4LtZ404/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well one of the few ideas I had turned out to be incorrect but I might use it so at the very least thank you for the idea :P

Comment: Lovely lovely puzzle. ROT13( V abgrq gung rirel 3k3 obk unq ab ercrngrq qvtvgf naq gurersber gubhtug vg unq fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu erneenatvat 3k3 obkrf. Vg arire bppheerq gb zr gung gur prageny tevq pbhyq or fbyinoyr )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have seen, the 9 sudokus are generally unsolvable because they have numbers which repeat in rows and/or columns. However, there is one exception, which is the central sudoku. It turns out it is solvable and with a unique solution:

[image]

There is something striking about the solution, namely that the central 3x3 square has a very nice ordering of its numbers. Suppose the central sudoku is a mapping of the total sudoku such that each 3x3 square in the central sudoku shows how each 9x9 sudoku has had its 3x3 squares moved around. For example, in the top left 3x3 square of the central sudoku, the number 1 is in the middle of the left column. Suppose this means that the top left 9x9 sudoku has had its "number 1" 3x3 square moved to the middle of its left column, when it should in fact have been at the top left (in the order given by the central suduko's central square). If we rearrange the position of each 3x3 square of each 9x9 suduko so it matches the ordering of the central sudoku's central square, we get this:

[image]

And if we then check each 9x9 sudoku, we see that there are no longer any repeats of numbers in rows or columns. In fact, each of the sudokus are now solvable and with unique solutions:

[image]

Comment: This is a really nice spot! But I think your middle picture might be in error as things stand - it seems to be the same as the first without the central 9x9 (nothing has changed position...)?

Comment: @Stiv Arghh, you are right. Will fix...

Comment: @Stiv Should be fixed now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: *The moderator, freed from the Sudoku, peers at you suspiciously. They shake their head, and vanish into moderator-land*